# Is there any YUM to APT-GET tool?

Tags: 12.04, server, apt, package-management, dpkg

I have a big source code where it wants to install everything where shown of YUM (Fedora, CentOS, Red hat package manager).

Example:

```
$ yum install bzip2 cpio curl curl-devel fileutils gettext-devel libtool make nmap openssl openssl-devel libxml2 libxml2-devel php php-devel php-common php-cli php-gd php-pear php-mysql php-pdo php-pecl-json mysql mysql-server mysql-devel YAML

root@sun-M14xR2:/var/tmp# apt-get install bzip2 cpio curl curl-devel fileutils gettext-devel libtool make nmap openssl openssl-devel libxml2 libxml2-devel php php-devel php-common php-cli php-gd php-pear php-mysql php-pdo php-pecl-json mysql mysql-server mysql-devel YAML
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package fileutils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package curl-devel
E: Package 'fileutils' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package gettext-devel
E: Unable to locate package openssl-devel
E: Unable to locate package libxml2-devel
E: Unable to locate package php
E: Unable to locate package php-devel
E: Unable to locate package php-common
E: Unable to locate package php-cli
E: Unable to locate package php-gd
E: Unable to locate package php-mysql
E: Unable to locate package php-pdo
E: Unable to locate package php-pecl-json
E: Unable to locate package mysql
E: Unable to locate package mysql-devel
E: Unable to locate package YAML
```

And many many other yum package names. it will be lot of time consuming to find them one by one for Ubuntu, is there any yum to apt-get package translator?

But how do i interpret it for Ubuntu apt-get ??

Comment: Take out all that says `Unable to locate package` from the apt-get command.

Comment: How to find there accurate name automatically?

Comment: Such as gettext-devel openssl-devel libxml2-devel yaml etc?

Comment: In Ubuntu dev packages will have `-dev` suffix instead of `-devel`. I am composing the list of corresponding packages in Ubuntu

Comment: `sudo apt-get install build-essential `
`sudo apt-get install bzip2 cpio curl libtool openssl php5 php5-dev php5-common php5-cli php5-gd php5-mysql mysql-server mysql-source-5.5 libxml2 libxml2-dev gettext nmap`

Comment: @thefourtheye That just worked for me with an Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have not tried this in a very long time, but you can use a program called [alien](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/alien) for installing rpm packages in ubuntu